# Maxima: Why does solve return nothing

Tags: solver, maxima

I want solve to return the value of t1, which is the only unknown variable. But instead it returns `(%o3) []` and I don't understand why.

find_root does what is expected and returns value of t1 but I'd like to understand what is the source of the problem.

```
kill(all);
CIFV(K,r,t,m):= K*(1+r/m)^(t*m);
eq1: (CIFV(1000,0.06,t1,2)=1500);
solve(%,t1);
find_root(eq1,t1,0,100);
```

Comment: Please explain the intended output and what you're actually getting throughly.

Comment: Intended is for solve to return value of t1 which is the only unknown variable. But instead it returns this - (%o3) [] and I don't understand why. find_root does what is expected and returns value of t1.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that `solve` is meant to solve algebraic equations and your equation has the unknown as an exponent.

Given the equation 2^x=3 `solve` will correctly give `[x=log(3)/log(2)]`.
However the equation `1.5^x=1` will be interpreted as short for `(3/2)^x=1` and will end up giving the result `[3^x=2^x]`.

A workaround is to solve your equation symbolically and then substitute values after.

```
(%i13) solve(CIFV(K,r,t,m)=1500,t);
(%o13) [t=log(1500/K)/(m*log(r/m+1))]
```

Comment: Note: I attempted to use `keepfloat:true` to prevent `rat` from rewriting 3.1 into 31/10, but `solve` ignored it. Maybe there is a way for solve to pickup on this?

Comment: According to the following link, it is a bug in `solve` that prevents the `keepfloat:true` setting to be ignored. http://osdir.com/ml/mathematics.maxima.general/2003-06/msg00038.html